# Objective-C, EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

My problem here is that I disabled ARC for MyViewController (to be able to use a specific encryption lib) and now I get this :

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
```

when I try to access an array..
Anyone knows what I can do to solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't disable ARC for `MyViewController`. You should be able to make calls to a manual reference count class or function from an ARC class. If you have trouble calling this "specific encryption lib" from an ARC class, then post a question about that.

Comment: [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease]; This is the line that causes trouble with ARC. It says that autorelease is unavailable in automatic reference counting mode

Comment: I managed to remove the autorelease correctly and it works fine thank you for your answer (I removed autorelease and a set of [])